# radsplitter on master page - adjust content height on page load

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I'm using the Telerik RadSplitter on my site as a collapsible nav container. But I want the Nav in the SiteMaster (aspx with C# behind). When the page loads, the RadPane is not growing to fit the loaded page content. Seems like the Splitter is not recognizing the content size.

SITE.MASTER CODE:

```
<telerik:RadSplitter ID="RadSplitter1" runat="server" Height="98%" Width="100%">
           <telerik:RadPane runat="server" ID="RadPane1" Width="13%" Height="100%">
                <telerik:RadTreeView ID="MyTreeView" runat="server">
                <Nodes>
                    <telerik:RadTreeNode Value="Child1" Expanded="False" Text="Aging Reports">
                        <Nodes>
                            <telerik:RadTreeNode Value="Grandchild1" Text="Failed Inspections" />
                            <telerik:RadTreeNode Value="Grandchild2" Text="Pre-Con Inspections" />
                            <telerik:RadTreeNode Value="Grandchild3" Text="Pre-Drywall Inspections" />
                        </Nodes>
                    </telerik:RadTreeNode>
                    <telerik:RadTreeNode Value="Child2" Expanded="False" Text="Accounting">
                        <Nodes>
                            <telerik:RadTreeNode Value="Grandchild1" Text="Top/Bottom Profits" />
                        </Nodes>
                    </telerik:RadTreeNode>
                    <telerik:RadTreeNode Value="Child3" Expanded="False" Text="LG&E Commercial">
                        <Nodes>
                            <telerik:RadTreeNode Value="Grandchild1" Text="ECM/VRM Management" />
                        </Nodes>
                    </telerik:RadTreeNode>
                    <telerik:RadTreeNode Value="Child4" Expanded="False" Text="LG&E ESH Program">
                    </telerik:RadTreeNode>
                    <telerik:RadTreeNode Value="Child5" Expanded="False" Text="MA Office Management">
                        <Nodes>
                            <telerik:RadTreeNode Value="Grandchild1" Text="Inventory Control (MICS)" />
                        </Nodes>
                    </telerik:RadTreeNode>

                </Nodes>
            </telerik:RadTreeView>
           </telerik:RadPane>
           <telerik:RadSplitBar runat="server" ID="RadSplitbar1" CollapseMode="Forward">
           </telerik:RadSplitBar>
           <telerik:RadPane runat="server" ID="Radpane2" Width="85%" Height="100%">
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" />
           </telerik:RadPane>
      </telerik:RadSplitter>
```

Thanks in advance.
Gabe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will find the ideas here useful: http://www.telerik.com/support/kb/aspnet-ajax/splitter/initially-resize-the-radsplitter-according-to-its-content.aspx. You may need to use the pageLoad() shortcut, to make sure you don't get a race condition with the order of the controls' initialization.

You can adapt the logic to use other events like OnClientExpanded (http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/splitter-client-side-onclientexpanded.html) or OnClientNodeExpanded (http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/treeview-onclientnodeexpanded.html) depending on your needs.